# What do the model numbers on Bastion's body represent?

Tags: overwatch

On Bastion's normal skins, the model number is E54.

On Bastion's Omnic Crisis skin, the model number is B73.

On Bastion's Defense Matrix skin, the model number is UI02.

Do these models reference any specific kind of Omnic at all? Or are they completely random and have nothing to do with Bastion?

Comment: I'm guessing you had meant to tag bastion as a character. It seems, at best, [the vote to start creating character tags is still out](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/do-we-want-tags-for-specific-heroes-or-roles-in-overwatch) but the tag [tag:bastion] is actually for [the game "Bastion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_%28video_game%29).

Comment: @Timelord64 oops, totally didn't see that and glossed over the tag, thanks for fixing it :)

Comment: I have a feeling the E54 is a reference to [the recurring theme of the number appearing in Blizzard's games.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-number-54-in-blizzards-games) No idea what the other numbers mean, if anything, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official lore for what the numbers mean but I would presume they are version, unit or batch numbers. I doubt they reference a specific kind of Omnic robot as Bastion is the type, not his name as might be thought.

From Overwatch's website character lore

> Originally created for peacekeeping purposes, **Bastion robot units**
>   possessed the unique ability to rapidly reconfigure themselves into an
>   assault-cannon mode.

*(Emphasis added)*

Answer (score -1):

They are in fact Jeff Kaplans step daughters idea. e54 was her minecraft username and he says "I always recall hearing 'Jeff look!' and seeing the numbers 'e54' sprinting towards me."

Comment: You are correct, but linking a source would make this a much better answer.